# When try call method every minute it called just twice

Tags: c#, timespan

When I call `ScheduleBackUp()` in `form_load` the method execute just twice!

this is my class:

```
class BackupDBs : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private readonly object _lock = new object();
        private int _state = -1;
        string nameBackupFolder;    

        public void ScheduleBackUp()
        {
            var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
            { 
                DoBackup();
            }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);

        }

        public int MyState
        {
            get
            {
                return _state;
            }
            set
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (value != _state)
                    {
                        _state = value;
                        NotifyStateChanged("MyState");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void NotifyStateChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void DoBackup()
        {
            MyState = 0;

            try
            {
                MyState = 1;
                MyState = 2;
                CreateBackupFolder();
            }
            catch
            {
                MyState = 3;                
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                var con = new MainCon();
                con.sqlQuery("BACKUP DATABASE [" + DataCenter.DEFAULT_DB_NAME + "] TO DISK='" + nameBackupFolder + "\\" + DataCenter.DEFAULT_DB_NAME + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") + ".bak'");

                con.nonQueryEx();
                con.closecon();

                MyState = 4;
            }
            catch
            {
                MyState = 5;                
            }
        }

 public void CreateBackupFolder()
        {
            //couz we need create to each DB special folder so we need to get the descr of default DB           
            string desc = DataCenter.DEFAULT_DB_DESCRIPTION;

            //Get the default path for backup
            string pathBackup = DataCenter.BACKUP_PATH;

            //Preaper the name for our folder
            nameBackupFolder = pathBackup + @"\" + "backup for " + desc;

            // Create a new target folder, if not exists.
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(nameBackupFolder))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(nameBackupFolder);
            }
        }
```

I use this to call the method :

```
private Classes.BackupDBs budb = new Classes.BackupDBs();
budb.ScheduleBackUp();
```

Just two successful backup happened then nothing happened.
Kindly what did I miss?

Comment: [Why does System.Threading.Timer stop on its own?](//stackoverflow.com/a/2196830) (The local variable `timer` is being garbage collected).

Comment: I would start by not ignoring exceptions as it might give you more information. You can either change your catches to catch known errors (ideal) or to at least log the error somewhere: `catch (Exception ex) {  _logger.Error(ex); }`.

Comment: @Laurence thank you BUT as in my code when catch happened it change the state and I have list in UI hold changes so I will know if some thing wrong happened, nothing wrong in `DoBackup();` method .

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you so much but I will be very happy to understand why it went out of scope? what the reason for that ?

Comment: @Nano `timer` is a local variable - it only exists inside the function `ScheduleBackUp()`. Once you exit that function, the system is free to GC it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to move the declaration of `timer` up to your form fields, so it doesn't go out of scope and recycled.

Your fields should look like this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private readonly object _lock = new object();
private int _state = -1;
string nameBackupFolder;    

System.Threading.Timer timer;
```

Now in `ScheduleBackup()`, do:

```
timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
{ 
    DoBackup();
}, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

Now it will work forever.

Comment: That work BUT please do not forget you can declare `var` just for local verbals so I replaced `var` by `private System.Threading.Timer timer;` 

Thank you so much but I will be happy to understand why it went out of scope? what the reason for that ?

Comment: Local variables go out of scope, when you exit the method.